# Why does the Form1_Load method not get called when the program runs

Tags: c#, winforms

Below is part of a program located in the Form1.cs file to populate the domainUpDown widget with values when the program starts.
I'm calling the method when Form1 loads.

Form1 loads when the program starts up, but the Form1_Load method never fires.

Why is the Form1_Load method not firing?

```
         private void BindDomainIUpDown()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 999; i++)
            {
                domainUpDown1.Items.Add(i);
            }
            domainUpDown1.Text = "100";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindDomainIUpDown();

        }
```

Comment: Did you subscribe to that method?

Comment: Is the form configured to call the method? If you just created the method from scratch and didn't add it to the form properties, it won't get called.

Comment: It's likely that the Form1.Load method is not handled by your method, check in the Form1.Designer.cs and make sure there is a line for Form1.Load += Form1_Load

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure the method `Form1_Load` is bound to your event.

You can do this in multiple ways :

1- Go to Designer > Right Click form > Properties > Events > Check if Form1_Load is available next to Load.

2- Right Click Form1_Load > Find All References > You must find a reference inside Form1.Designer.cs

3- Double click your form using the designer, if VS forwards you to the method, then it is bound. If VS created a new method `Form1_Load_1` then it is not bound.

**Or a quick fix** it to try to bind it in the constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Load += Form1_Load;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code to > form1.designer.cs

> > locate // Form 1

this.Load += new System.EventHanler(this.Form1_Load);

or

right click empty space in designer > load > choose from drop down the form1_load

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).